# How to navigate between screens in different stack navigators

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am unable to navigate from a settings screen inside MainView stack navigator to the Auth inside in App Stack navigator.

I have tried running this :

```
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Auth');
    this.props.navigation.navigate('AuthStack',{},
                NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'SignIn' }),
```

nothing happens I simply stay on the settings screen.

Route file

```
    const MainViewStack = createStackNavigator({
      Settings: {
          screen: Settings,
      },
    })

    const AuthStack = createStackNavigator(
      { SignIn: Login },
      {
        headerMode: 'none',
      },
    );
```

SettingScreen file

```
    handleLogout() {
       this.props.navigation.navigate('Auth');
    }
```

Comment: `this.props.navigation.navigate('AuthStack');`  Just do this.

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: Your route is called `SignIn`.     `this.props.navigation.navigate('SignIn');`

Comment: okay thanks the ('AuthStack') worked for me.